# SQL GROUP BY columns with inverted values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Suppose I've a table with like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|G1 |G2 |G3 |G4 | V |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D | 2 |
| E | F | G | H | 4 |
| C | D | A | B | 2 |
| E | F | G | H | 3 |
| E | I | G | L | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Where G1, G3 are VARCHAR and G2, G4 are INT

If I do a simple GROUP BY on G1..G4 I get:

```sql
SELECT G1,G2,G3,G4,SUM(V) as V FROM Table GROUP BY G1, G2, G3, G4;

    +---+---+---+---+---+
    |G1 |G2 |G3 |G4 | V |
    +---+---+---+---+---+
    | A | B | C | D | 2 |
    | E | F | G | H | 7 |
    | C | D | A | B | 2 |
    | E | I | G | L | 7 |
    +---+---+---+---+---+
```

I'm wondering if is possible to aggregate on inverted value G1,G2 <-> G3,G4.
What I want to achieve is a result like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+      +---+---+---+---+---+
|G1 |G2 |G3 |G4 | V |      |G1 |G2 |G3 |G4 | V |
+---+---+---+---+---+      +---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D | 4 |  OR  | C | D | A | B | 4 |
| E | F | G | H | 7 |      | E | F | G | H | 7 |
| E | I | G | L | 7 |      | E | I | G | L | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+---+      +---+---+---+---+---+
```

What I tried is to get the inverted rows, but I still can't aggregate on them due to repetition. My test query is:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Table t1
JOIN Table t2 on t1.G1 = t2.G3 and t1.G2=t2.G4 and t1.G3=t2.G1 and t1.G4=t2.G2

    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |G1 |G2 |G3 |G4 | V |G1 |G2 |G3 |G4 | V |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    | A | B | C | D | 2 | C | D | A | B | 2 |
    | C | D | A | B | 2 | A | B | C | D | 2 |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Inverted values". Is that a matrix thing or something? I'm not at all familiar with that terminology in regards to relational data.

Comment: Is it always ABCD or CDAB or can you have BADC for example and should it be counted as different? You might consider a simple hashing function like ord(G1)*ord(G2)*ord(G3)*ord(G4) as hash and group by it. Otherwise you can use IF or CASE functions as explained in the answer

Comment: Maybe I was too generic in the question. I added col types in the edit. Since G1,G3 are strings and G2,G4 are int the answer to @DobromirVelev is no, BADC is not allowed. 
Maybe the hashing function could be a better way to group them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've got it right, reverse the order of columns so that A B C D matches C D A B .

```
select 
         case when(g1 > g3) then g3 else g1 end G1,
         case when(g1 > g3) then g4 else g2 end G2,
         case when(g1 > g3) then g1 else g3 end G3,
         case when(g1 > g3) then g2 else g4 end G4, sum(V)
from tbl
group by case when(g1 > g3) then g3 else g1 end,
         case when(g1 > g3) then g4 else g2 end,
         case when(g1 > g3) then g1 else g3 end,
         case when(g1 > g3) then g2 else g4 end
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d346475abaf5f517ed8813ab3836c354)

Comment: Nice one - I would have used SELECT IF(g1 > g3,g3,g1)  as F1, IF(g1 > g3,g4,g2)  as F2, IF(g1 > g3,g1,g3)  as F3, IF(g1 > g3,g2,g4)  as F4, sum(V) FROM tbl GROUP BY F1,F2,F3,F4; but the logic is the same

Comment: @DobromirVelev,   yes quite reasonable use of MySql IF. I just used the standard SQL syntax .

Comment: I'm using MySQL, so if the IF is better in performance maybe I can use it. Btw I added info about col types, since I used the words for generic value. I think 'case when' will not work anymore :(

Comment: @TheEnigmist, yes, it will work with char and int too. Added the fiddle  to the answer.  `>` is a valid  char comparison oper and it is deterministic. That's all we need for the solution to work.

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks a lot! I've a question, will IF statement run better in terms of performance?

Comment: @TheEnigmist,  I don't anticipate any substantial difference.

Comment: Ok thanks, I read another comment about CASE | IF | IF func and seems to be the same, the CASE is better since it is SQL standard and is more flexible.